# 6 sub-DIV's, one container DIV, Grouped in 3 pairs of 2, left,center,right justified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Was my title strong enough?

I want a DIV that goes a horizontal length of a page, then I want 6 divs inside of that that are grouped in 2 (info, pic) Where the group on the left is fastened to the wall, the group on the right is fastened to the wall, and the group in the center is exactly in the center.

Here's my code so far:

```
<div class="contactus.container">

<div class="contactus.left">
    <div><b>asdf</b></div>
    <div><b>sadf</b></div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>sadf</div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>af</div>
</div>
<div class="content" style="display:inline-block" >
    <img align="left" alt="pic" class="bold" 
        src="profilepic.jpg" 
        style="width: 125px; height: 125px;" vspace="0" />
</div>

<div class="contactus.center">
    <div><b>asdf</b></div>
    <div><b>sadf</b></div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>sadf</div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>af</div>
</div>

<div class="content" style="display:inline-block">
    <img align="left" alt="pic" class="bold" 
        src="profilepic.jpg" 
        style="width: 125px; height: 125px;" vspace="0" />
</div>

<div class="contactus.right">
    <div><b>asdf</b></div>
    <div><b>sadf</b></div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>sadf</div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>asdf</div>
    <div>af</div>
</div>

<div class="content" style="display:inline-block;">
    <img align="right" alt="pic" class="bold" 
        src="profilepic.jpg" 
        style="width: 125px; height: 125px;" vspace="0" />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.contactus.container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.contactus.left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}

.contactus.center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
}

.contactus.right {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
} 

.content {
    display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
```

Getting al ittle frustrated now. All it does is have a line down the left side. All 6 divs.

Comment: Try `display:table-cell`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use a `.` in your CSS class names. As such, `class="contactus.center"` or `class="contactus.right"` will not work the way you have it here.

Answer (score 2):

First thing's first, you cannot use `.` inside your class name, as mentioned by @grammar in the comments (props to @Scot for copying it to an answer). When you make a reference to `.contactus.left` in your css, it will look for an element with two classes, like `class="contactus left"`. For the divs you have with class names like `contactus.left`, you could either give them two separate classes, like `<div class="contactus left">` or use a separator like an underscore or a hyphen, such as `<div class="contactus-left">`.

However, correcting that will not solve your problem. As for what you are trying to accomplish, I believe you mean to say that you want 2 groups of 3 (left, center, and right). To accomplish this, you will want each sub-div to have the `display: inline-block` style instead of just the center div, and to make sure the center div is actually centered on the page, you will want to divide up the width of the container amongst the three inner divs, and assign the appropriate text-align value to each.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cnvqqr9/).

You can manage the div sizing yourself, just assigning a percentage for the width of each div. Alternatively, there are css frameworks like [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) that help you manage your page layout with a grid system that basically uses percentages and inline-block elements, and provide you with intuitive class names to easily put your content where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have named and formatted your classes incorrectly.

Try renaming the css classes like this:

```
 .contactus_center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
}
```

and your HTML like this:

```
<div class="contactus_center">
```